# Jquery Datepicker is not displayed

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I try to implement a datepicker inside a modal window. I don't know why the error toggle is not working. I included all the header files. I tried in a seperate file which worked correctly, but after I included it in my website it didn't worked.

Headers:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/landing-page.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" media="screen"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="assets/css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Date Of Birth" name="dateofbirth" id="dateofbirth">
```

Script:

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
<script src="js/script.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.backstretch("assets/img/login-bg1.jpg", {speed: 500});
    $('#dateofbirth').datetimepicker
        ({
             autoclose: 1,
             todayHighlight: 1,
             startView: 2,
             minView: 3,
             maxView: 4,
             forceParse: 0,
             format:'dd-mm-yyyy'
         });
    addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Put your datetimepicker code in document ready section.

Comment: Check your browser console and see How many errors are displayed there?

Comment: No error is coming. thats the problem. thats why i cannot find exactly whats went wrong.

Comment: No error in console tab? strange.

Comment: Why you have two scripts of jquery in your html? And bootstrap datetimepicker require moment.js. Try by including that too.

Comment: Now i change it with single script and i add header file still it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to bind an element to an event before the element and/or needed scripts are loaded onto your page.

Change your javascript to this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.backstretch("assets/img/login-bg1.jpg", {speed: 500});
        $('#dateofbirth').datetimepicker
            ({
                 autoclose: 1,
                 todayHighlight: 1,
                 startView: 2,
                 minView: 3,
                 maxView: 4,
                 forceParse: 0,
                 format:'dd-mm-yyyy'
             });
        addEventListener('load', prettyPrint, false);
        $('pre').addClass('prettyprint linenums');
    });
```

Comment: i tried like this way bt as like previous datepicker is not working.no changes i can found here. please help me in someother way.

Comment: Try datepicker(); is my only guess since I've never used datetimepicker and perhaps the arguments you're using are invalid for that function call?

Comment: I tried that in someother way now it is working.Thanks for the help.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the changes that you had to make to get it to work.

Comment: Yeah i change it now.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('#dateofbirth').datetimepicker()
```

to

```
$('#dateofbirth').datepicker()
```

I have a working example on jsbin. You can view this [here](https://jsbin.com/zapigadiki/edit?html).

You can view its full page output [here](https://output.jsbin.com/zapigadiki).

Comment: i tried this way it is showing $(...)datepicker is not a function error in console tab